# Replace the last element in a list with another list

Tags: python

For example I have two arrays a `array1` and `array2`

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',]
array2 = ['G', 'H', 'I',]`
```

Now I want the output as

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I',]
```

How can I do this in python

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> array2 = ['G', 'H', 'I']
>>> array1 = array1[:-1] + array2
>>> array1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Answer (score 19):

To replace parts of a python list, you can use slice assignment:

```
>>> array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> array2 = ['G', 'H', 'I']
>>> array1[-1:] = array2
>>> array1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

You can use slice assignment to replace any part of a list, including insertion of lists where you do not replace existing elements:

```
>>> array1[0:0] = ['1st', '2nd']
>>> array1
['1st', '2nd', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Here the `[0:0]` slice selects an empty part of `array1` and "replaces" it with the new elements.

Comment: Removed the in-place alternative from my solution since you had it here first.

Comment: @jamylak: tough, your post already had my vote. :-) Updated to illustrate another slice assignment trick to further explain what is going on.

Comment: Take back the vote if you believe this is the better way, I think this seems much more pythonic.

Comment: @jamylak: both approaches are valid; I *think* the OP meant to alter `array1` as I have done, but that isn't 100% clear either.

Answer (score 0):

When chaining arrays, it may be useful using itertools:

```
import itertools
array1 = itertools.chain(array1[:-1], array2)
```

That's it.

Doc: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Comment: That doesn't address the "replace the last element" aspect.  In fact, since you don't call `list` or assign the result to `array1`, right now the code doesn't do anything.

Comment: You're right. I missed that point. Just edited to take it into account and do the assignation which was kind of obvious. ;)

Comment: `itertools.chain` doesn't return a list.  It returns an `itertools.chain` object.

Comment: Indeed but depending on the use case it's OK as it's as iterable as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution in Python3:

```
>>> array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',]
>>> array2 = ['G', 'H', 'I',]
>>> array1 = [*array1[:-1], *array2]
>>> array1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> array1.remove(array1[len(array1)-1])
>>> for i in array2:
        array1.append(i)
```

Kinda Naive but works..

Comment: Use `array1.pop()` instead. Then you can just do: `array1 += array2`.

Comment: Not just naive but (a lot) slower for large lists too.

Comment: This will only work if the last member of the list only occurs once.  If `array1 = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]` then remove will take the wrong `"A"`..

Comment: Never *ever* use list.remove unless your removal criteria is *actually* to remove an element with a particular value, when you don't know/care where it is in the list. If your removal criteria is based on position (as in this case) or any other kind of criteria, there is *always* a better way than "find the element I want to remove then call remove". list.remove is needlessly slow if you've already found the element by some other means, and frequently does the wrong thing in such cases, as explained by DSM's comment.